# How can I spin an object each 5 seconds in other random values?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToSpin;
    public float spinX;
    public float spinY;
    public float spinZ;
    public bool randomSpin = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        var rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.angularVelocity = Random.insideUnitSphere;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (randomSpin == true)
        {
            objectToSpin.transform.Rotate(Random.Range(spinX, 360), Random.Range(spinY, 360), Random.Range(spinZ, 360));
        }
        else
        {
            objectToSpin.transform.Rotate(spinX, spinY, spinZ);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when changing the randomSpin flag to true it will spin random nonstop changing random angle on x y z each frame.

But I want it to spin random for 5 seconds after 5 seconds to change to random values the x y z and continue from last point and then after 5 seconds random angles and so on.

Comment: Is only the direction supposed to be random or should the speed be random too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a constant speed and just a random direction, You can randomly select an Axis to rotate around using `Random.onUnitSphere` and then rotate around it at a speed.

Here's a solution that uses a Coroutine. If you want to stop the Coroutine, you can use `StopCoroutine("Spin")` to stop the coroutine and start it up later with `StartCoroutine("Spin")`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToSpin;
    public Vector3 spinAxis;
    public float timeToSpin = 5f;
    public float spinSpeed = 20f;
    public bool randomSpin = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        var rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.angularVelocity = Random.insideUnitSphere;
        StartCoroutine("Spin");
    }

    private void Update()
    {
    }
}

IEnumerator Spin() 
{
    float spinTimer;
    while (true)
    {
        if (randomSpin == true)
        { 
            spinAxis = Random.onUnitSphere;
        }

        spinTimer = timeToSpin;
        while (spinTimer > 0f) 
        {
            objectToSpin.transform.Rotate(spinAxis, Time.deltaTime * spinSpeed);
            spinTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example have a simple timer using `Time.deltaTime` like e.g.

```
private float timer = 5;

private void Update()
{
    if (randomSpin == true)
    {
         timer -= Time.deltaTime;
         if(timer <= 0)
         {
            objectToSpin.transform.Rotate(Random.Range(spinX, 360), Random.Range(spinY, 360), Random.Range(spinZ, 360));

            timer = 5;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        objectToSpin.transform.Rotate(spinX, spinY, spinZ);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's changing the angles each 5 seconds but I asked the question by mistake I guess. I want it to rotate for 5 seconds then it will change for random x y z and then will rotate for 5 seconds then change random again and then rotate 5 seconds. In other words it should rotate all the time and change randomly the xyz every 5 seconds.

Comment: Oh that's something different ^^